# Logout in Single Sign On with WIF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, single-sign-on, wif

I have integrated my application with single sign on application with WIF using claims .

My problem is I am  not able to logout of the system by clearing the claims.
Suppose I hit the URL as:
**http:localhost/login.aspx** it is still in live state.

I have used these two lines of code,but still not logging out

**FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut();**

Any suggestion on how to sign out of the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `FederatedPassiveSignInStatus` (should be in your Toolbox). Set the property `SignOutAction` to `FederatedSignOut` and the control will clear out your STS session as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your dev tools in the browser, Resources Tab, Cookies and see what is keeping you signed in. No point in guessing.